# BIOS not able to boot from USB

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, bios, hp-pavilion

I'm using an HP Pavilion dv7-3165 dx. (BIOS version F15 of Insyde H20)

I can go into the boot selection menu by tapping ESC, and then F9, and I can see my TOSHIBA EXT HDD, but whenever I plug in a USB stick my BIOS will not load. It will freeze on the POST (the blue HP logo and the message "press ESC to bios option" will remain on screen).

I have tried many otpions inside the BIOS config, but none has resulted in anything.

If anyone has faced the same problem, or knows a solution, please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you reported this to the vendor i.e. HP?